# Normalized statistical measure for agreement of biological replicates

Tags: standard-deviation, normalization, coefficient-of-variation

I've conducted an experiment collecting samples from various depths in the ocean. At each depth, I collected 3 samples to act as biological replicates. I now want to show that all of my replicates show good agreement to the mean values. But I don't want to list all of the mean values for each sample with a corresponding standard error. Is there a test I can perform to provide me with one number showing the average normalized variation in my replicates for all of my depths? To be clear, I'm not trying to say anything about the different values I measured at each depth. I just want to show that all of my biological replicates are in good agreement with the mean of their values.
Cheers.

Comment: i don't think you can do a test for this. you can normalize the standard deviation to mean, and it's normally called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation . You have this for every sample.. don't know if this is what you need

Comment: Thanks for your help. If i calculate the CV for each sample, am I then able to take the average of all of my CV's to get a sort of pooled CV for my whole depth profile? Or is that inappropriate?

Comment: I think it's ok, but i guess you need to explain what it is.. more like on average the coefficient of variation is .. , and this means on average the standard deviation is say 0.5 of the mean etc..

Comment: Just to clarify, it's 1 measurement per sample at various depth right